# convert json to csv using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How to convert the Json file to csv file using python pandas
Reading file:

```
with open('temp.txt') as f:
    content = f.read().replce('U','')
d=json.loads(content)
```

Input:

```
 {"D":{
    "1":"66",
    "2":"77",
    "3":"3"
},"A":{
    "11":"166",
    "12":"177",
    "13":"13"
}}U
{"X":{
"2":"5",
"3":"4"}}U
{"E":{
"4":"55",
"6":"33"}}U
```

output csv file should be

```
    D1,D2,D3,A11,A12,A13,X2,X3,E4,E6
66,77,3,166,177,13,NA,NA,NA,NA
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,5,4,NA,NA
NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,55,33
```

Comment: Please read documentation before posting such questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('test.json') as f:
    content = f.read().replace('U',',')[::-1].replace(',', '', 1)[::-1]
    content = '[{}]'.format(content)

l = json.loads(content)
d = [{k1+k2: v2 for k2,v2 in v1.items()} for x in l for k1,v1 in x.items()]

df = pd.DataFrame(d2, columns=[k for x in d for k in x.keys()])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
    D1   D2   D3  A11  A12  A13   X2   X3   E4   E6
0   66   77    3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  166  177   13  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    5    4  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   55   33
```

And to save to a CSV file: `df.to_csv(filename, index=False)`

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189625/discussion-on-answer-by-perl-convert-json-to-csv-using-python-pandas).

Comment: @perl can you look up my new question here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902920/read-file-by-removing-the-unwanted-lines-using-python-pandas?noredirect=1#comment102227251_57902920

Comment: @perl can you look up my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58305085/iterate-over-dataframe-and-calculate-min-value-for-every-5-minutes-for-particula/58305242?noredirect=1#comment102972863_58305242