# Read file by removing the unwanted lines using python pandas

Tags: python-2.7

I am reading a file which contains json data and in between it contains other text.So for that i want to check that condition on reading the file if line starts with condition how can i achieve this?

```
 with open ("inputfile.txt") as f:
    content = f.read().replace('}U','},')[::-1].replace(',', '', 1)].replace(":[",":").replace("]","")
    content = '[{}]'.format(content)
 data=json.loads(content)
```

**I want to check the file if the line starts with condition like this**

```
startswith("{"+"\"M\""+":")
```

I Have tried reading line by line and checking if the line startswith condition but for large files it is tak

inputfile.txt

```
sometext
{"M":{"1":"data","2":"data2"}}U
asdklaasd
{"M":{"3":"555","5":"3333"}}U
```

I want to read the lines only that **start with {"M":**

Output I need is like this

```
[{"M":{"1":"data","2":"data2"}},{"M":{"3":"555","5":"3333"}}]
```

Comment: What does this have to do with pandas? Also, pandas has dropped support for python 2, you should switch to 3 if you can.

Comment: Okay.How can i achieve this using python2?

Comment: Post some sample input and outputs to make it clear what you are trying to do?

Comment: @Dan just posted input data and output data

Comment: @Dan can you give me the answer

Comment: have you tried it line by line to make sure it's too slow? But you could probably do it with regex, you'd have to figure out how to match `{"M"` with the correct closing `}` though, but if you can then you could possibly do it in one shot. Not sure if that would be faster.