# Iterate over Dataframe and calculate min value for every 5 minutes for particular symbol

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
dataframe
symbol,Time,Day,x_value,y_value
aaa,2018-09-21 11:01:00,saturday,1,2
aaa,2018-09-21 11:02:00,saturday,2,5
aaa,2018-09-21 11:03:00,saturday,5,1
aaa,2018-09-21 11:04:00,saturday,7,3
aaa,2018-09-21 11:05:00,saturday,6,4
aaa,2018-09-21 11:06:00,saturday,2,2
aaa,2018-09-21 11:07:00,saturday,3,5
aaa,2018-09-21 11:08:00,saturday,2,2
aaa,2018-09-21 11:09:00,saturday,2,3
aaa,2018-09-21 11:09:15,saturday,2,5
aaa,2018-09-21 11:10:00,saturday,2,3

output
symbol,day,start,end,count,x_value,y_value
aaa,saturday,11:01:00,11:10:00,5,13,15
```

Explanation:
Iterate over Dataframe and calculate min value for x_value and y_value for every 5 minutes for particular symbol and convert that dataframe to csv.

Comment: So are you asking us something or telling us what to do?

Comment: Yes How can i get that output.

Answer (score 1):

Use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df_new = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key = 'Time', freq='5 min'), 'symbol', 'Day'])
                                              .agg({'x_value': 'min', 'y_value': 'min'})
                                              .reset_index()
df_new['Time_End'] = df_new['Time'].shift(-1) - pd.Timedelta('1s')
df_new

            Time        symbol  Day     x_value y_value  Time_End
0   2018-09-21 11:00:00 aaa   saturday  1         1      2018-09-21 11:04:59
1   2018-09-21 11:05:00 aaa   saturday  2         2      2018-09-21 11:09:59
2   2018-09-21 11:10:00 aaa   saturday  2         3         NaT
```

Comment: How can i get the Symbol,Day,start and end columns.

Comment: @raam I have made few changes please have a look

Comment: We have to sum the x_value and y_value for every 5mins and get the min value for each x_value and y_value for each symbol

Comment: @raam uhm how do you calculate the time start and time end? are they the max and minimum values too?

Comment: They are start =min of time for particular time and day and end =max of time for particular time and day

Comment: @ Mohit Motwani can you ans my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58434717/group-dataframe-with-until-column-value-meets-the-condition?noredirect=1#comment103210376_58434717