# Group dataframe with until column value meets the condition

Tags: python, pandas

I am having the following data frame need group the frame based on the condition
Data Frame

```
date,day,Name,value,orinal_Time_amin,diff
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,21,2019-09-23 00:41:00,0
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,5460,2019-09-23 00:45:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,2742,2019-09-23 00:50:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,13552,2019-09-23 00:55:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,6178,2019-09-23 01:24:00,25
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,171,2019-09-23 01:25:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,763,2019-09-23 01:30:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,1694,2019-09-23 01:35:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,164,2019-09-23 02:05:00,35
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,162,2019-09-23 02:10:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,162,2019-09-23 02:41:00,31
```

output

```
Day Name min.value min.time max.time
Monday ABCD 21 2019-09-23 00:41:00 2019-09-23 01:35:00
Monday ABCD 162 2019-09-23 02:05:00 2019-09-23 02:10:00
Monday ABCD 162 2019-09-23 02:41:00 2019-09-23 02:41:00
```

Explanation

```
I want to group the dataframe with Day,name,date until the diff <30 and get min value.
```

Comment: Please read [mcve].  I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I need to group all the rows in data frame until the value of diff column <30 and start a new row after the >30

Comment: In your output shouldn't it be 3 groups as the last entry in your sample data is above 30?

Comment: @Michael Gardner sorry It should be 3 groups.Updated my output

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

Data:

```
date,day,Name,value,orinal_Time_amin,diff
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,21,2019-09-23 00:41:00,0
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,5460,2019-09-23 00:45:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,2742,2019-09-23 00:50:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,13552,2019-09-23 00:55:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,6178,2019-09-23 01:24:00,25
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,171,2019-09-23 01:25:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,763,2019-09-23 01:30:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,1694,2019-09-23 01:35:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,164,2019-09-23 02:05:00,35
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,162,2019-09-23 02:10:00,5
9/23/2019,Monday,ABCD,162,2019-09-23 02:41:00,31
```

Code:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',')

df['max.time'] = df.groupby(df['diff'].gt(30).cumsum())['orinal_Time_amin'].transform('max')
df['min.time'] = df.groupby(df['diff'].gt(30).cumsum())['orinal_Time_amin'].transform('min')
df['min.value'] = df.groupby(df['diff'].gt(30).cumsum())['value'].transform('min')

df[['day', 'Name', 'min.value', 'min.time', 'max.time']].drop_duplicates()

Out[1]: 
       day  Name  min.value             min.time             max.time
0   Monday  ABCD         21  2019-09-23 00:41:00  2019-09-23 01:35:00
8   Monday  ABCD        162  2019-09-23 02:05:00  2019-09-23 02:10:00
10  Monday  ABCD        162  2019-09-23 02:41:00  2019-09-23 02:41:00
```

Comment: This is not the output i need.can you provide me the final output.

Comment: @raam I added the data I used.  You should get the same output.

Comment: can you answer my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710471/group-the-columns-by-day-and-name-and-get-the-min-value-with-their-start-and-end