# group the columns by day and name and get the min value with their start and end using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

need to group the columns by day and name and get the min value with their start and end

```
dataframe

day name value start end duration
Wednesday AAA 1 10/23/2019 2:46  10/23/2019 3:09 00:23
Wednesday AAA 1 10/23/2019 5:20  10/23/2019 5:44 00:24
Wednesday AAA 1 10/23/2019 6:51  10/23/2019 8:14 01:23
Wednesday AAA 17602 10/23/2019 12:35 10/23/2019 12:38 00:03
Wednesday AAA 1155 10/23/2019 15:50 10/23/2019 15:54 00:04
```

logic

```
df.groupby(['day','name']).agg({'duration':[np.min,np.max],'start':[np.min,np.max],'end':[np.min,np.max],'value':[np.min,np.max]})
```

what i am getting

```
day name duration_min duration_max duration_max_start duration_max_end duration_min_start duration_min_end value_min value_max
Wednesday AAA 00:03 01:23 10/23/2019 6:51  10/23/2019 3:09 10/23/2019 12:35 10/23/2019 15:54 1  17602
```

but what should i getting

```
day name duration_min duration_max duration_max_start duration_max_end value_max duration_min_start duration_min_end value_min
Wednesday AAA 00:03 01:23 10/23/2019 6:51  10/23/2019 8:14 1 10/23/2019 12:35 10/23/2019 12:38 17602
```

what i want is need to get min value and max value by grouping with their start and end values

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the attributes on the same row where duration min and max occur. What you wrote is the min and max of each individual column, whether they are on the same row or not.

Use `idxmin` & `idxmax` to find the row where min and max values occur, then merge with the original frame:

```
idx = df.groupby(['day','name'])['duration'].agg(['idxmin','idxmax'])
idx.merge(df.add_suffix('_min'), left_on='idxmin', right_index=True) \
    .merge(df.add_suffix('_max'), left_on='idxmax', right_index=True) \
    [['duration_min', 'duration_max', 'start_min', 'end_min', 'start_max', 'end_max', 'value_min', 'value_max']]
```

Result:

```
day       | name | duration_min | duration_max | start_min           | end_min             | start_max           | end_max             | value_min | value_max
Wednesday | AAA  | 00:03        | 01:23        | 2019-10-23 12:35:00 | 2019-10-23 12:38:00 | 2019-10-23 06:51:00 | 2019-10-23 08:14:00 | 17602     | 1
```

Rename the columns as needed.

Comment: I am getting only this columns 'duration_min', 'duration_max', 'start_min', 'end_min', 'start_max', 'end_max', 'value_min', 'value_max'.not getting day and name

Comment: `day` and `name` are in the index. Call `reset_index` to get them put them into the columns.